# Validate an array of inputs bootstrap validator - Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, bootstrapvalidator

I have problems to validate in the client-side an array of inputs.
Validations do not look right. I think I'm doing the right thing.
I'm using the plugin bootstrap validator and laravel 5.2

[client-side validation photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZp0s.jpg)

js code:

```
$('#forma').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Valor no valido',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        }, 
        fields: {
            'vtcanp[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Codigo de moneda requerido'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'Código debe ser minimo de 3 y maximo 4 caracteres'


                    },
                }
            },
            'vtprep[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Descripción de moneda requerido'
                    }

                }
            }




        }
    });
```

table view code:

```
<td width="17%">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="vtcanp[]" /> 

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="17%">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="vtprep[]"/>

                                    </td>
```

Now It's validating but one tr only. When I add more tr it' not validating.

[Error tr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2r9A.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<form id="formid">
<div class="form-group" id="validatetr">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="17%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="vtcanp[]" /> 
            </td>
            <td width="17%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="vtprep[]"/>

            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form> //manage form according to your structure
```

Now where you add dynamically tr in response add this

```
var $template = $('#validatetr'),
$clone    = $template
$('#formid')
.formValidation('addField', $clone.find('[name="vtcanp[]"]'))
.formValidation('addField', $clone.find('[name="vtprep[]"]'))
```

Also Replace top of the part from this:-

```
 $('#forma')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
```

And this link might help you :- http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/

Hope it helps

Comment: have you include all the files (formvalidation.js,bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css)?

Comment: Yes, I included all and it isn't form validation.js it's bootstrapvalidator.js

Comment: I included all the real files (formValidation.js, .css, etc) and not working yet )=

Comment: Now it's validating but one tr only and I need the validations in all dynamic tr....I updated my answer with a photo to show the problem

Comment: Any suggestion?  :(

Comment: yes i already told you i am also using bootstrap validation with these js files and css that i have mentioned above url

Comment: But when I add a table tr dynamically, doen't validate all. Only validate one tr

Comment: see my updated answer and go through the link i have mentioned

Comment: I'll try if it works. Although the problem is not so much because I am already adding a dynamic tr, only that does not validate the fields added, only validating the first tr

Comment: I tried to do it with your code, but I had another problem.
I attached a photo to show the problem.
https://ibb.co/emNgiQ
I think it´s working  but it is not showing the messages well in the inputs

Comment: glad to help not forget to upvote the right answer :p